# Is there any way to exclude the classpath entry while mentioning dependency in maven?

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven

Is there any way to exclude the classpath entry while mentioning dependency in maven?

I want to exclude the MANIFEST.MF file entry for the particular Maven Dependency. Dependency jar should be present in the WEB-INF/lib path. But It should not make entry to the MANIFEST.MF file.

Is it possible?

Comment: That is unusual. Why exclude from the MANIFEST.MF and still be present in WEB-INF/lib?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a built-in way to do this, it would probably be by editing the dependency's `<scope>` in the pom.  This resource may be helpful:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

Perhaps `<scope>runtime</scope>` will do what you want.  If not then I think the next best option would be to set `<scope>provided</scope>` and then use the [resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin) to manually copy your dependency JAR file to the desired location as part of your build.